# Sorry, there was a problem completing the installation

Tags: system-installation

Tried to install via ISO mapped throug ILO and USB, but installation failes. ISO I try to install is ubuntu-20.04.2-live-server-amd64.ISO. I have also Tried the 18.04.5 ISO.
I'm trying to install on an HPE Apollo 4500
Have installed same Ubuntu version on this kind of server on other implementations.

[image: error message]

Comment: Hello Lars, welcome to Ask Ubuntu. Can you edit your question to provide more information such as what machine are you installing it on, is there an existing operating system and possibly a picture of the screen ?

Comment: Sorry Lars, but I have to ask a stupid question: What is ILO?

Comment: Integrated Lights Out for HPE. It's a KVM-solution to manage physical servers

Comment: The first option (`[View full report    ]`) sounds interesing, doesn't it?

Comment: yes but does not say anything and it's not easy to read, many lines

Comment: Upload it to pastebin and put the link into your question, maybe someone will be able to offer a solution.

Comment: One idea I have is to search the log for the word "swap" and then see if the installer erases the target root partition's superblock shortly after that.  If that happened, I have a solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the option "Custom Storage Layout" for storage instead of default LVM, make sure you must have a "/boot" partition with 2 Gig space.  Also do not use up all the available space, leave a few Megabyte space for the installer itself (its own usage e.g. spacer), that should solve the problem. ( I figured it out after numerous trial and error !)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).